"torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory" when loading llama model with Flan v2 dataset
I am trying to fine tune the llama model meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct on the Flan v2 dataset FlanV2. I have an experiment function that is the first thing that will be run, where I try to load my model
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig 

import flan.v2.mixtures

def experiment():
    model_id = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct"
    access_token = "..."
    
    print(torch.cuda.memory_summary(device=None, abbreviated=False))

    quant_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=getattr(torch, "float16"),
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
    )

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_id,
        token=access_token,
        quantization_config=quant_config
    )

    print(torch.cuda.memory_summary(device=None, abbreviated=False))

However I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 34, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 29, in main
    experiment()
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 20, in experiment
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 563, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3677, in from_pretrained
    ) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 4104, in _load_pretrained_model
    new_error_msgs, offload_index, state_dict_index = _load_state_dict_into_meta_model(
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 888, in _load_state_dict_into_meta_model
    hf_quantizer.create_quantized_param(model, param, param_name, param_device, state_dict, unexpected_keys)
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/quantizers/quantizer_bnb_4bit.py", line 219, in create_quantized_param
    new_value = bnb.nn.Params4bit(new_value, requires_grad=False, **kwargs).to(target_device)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 191, in to
    return self.cuda(device)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 168, in cuda
    w = self.data.contiguous().half().cuda(device)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 112.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 23.64 GiB of which 42.50 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 23.60 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 1002.01 MiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.99 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management

I am running on a cluster where I have access to NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 and 4090 with 24GiB of memory per GPU. I intend to use the cot_zsopt dataset as shown in this example file run_example.py
I have tried to monitor my memory consumption to find the source of the problem and here is what I found
W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
|===========================================================================|
|                  PyTorch CUDA memory summary, device ID 0                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            CUDA OOMs: 0            |        cudaMalloc retries: 0         |
|===========================================================================|
|        Metric         | Cur Usage  | Peak Usage | Tot Alloc  | Tot Freed  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocated memory      |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active memory         |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Requested memory      |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved memory   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable memory |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocations           |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active allocs         |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved segments |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable allocs |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize allocations  |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize GPU segments |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|===========================================================================|

`low_cpu_mem_usage` was None, now set to True since model is quantized.

Loading checkpoint shards:   0%|          | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Loading checkpoint shards:   0%|          | 0/4 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 34, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 29, in main
    experiment()
  File "/cluster/home/username/afsl/examples/bug.py", line 20, in experiment
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 563, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3677, in from_pretrained
    ) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 4104, in _load_pretrained_model
    new_error_msgs, offload_index, state_dict_index = _load_state_dict_into_meta_model(
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 888, in _load_state_dict_into_meta_model
    hf_quantizer.create_quantized_param(model, param, param_name, param_device, state_dict, unexpected_keys)
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/quantizers/quantizer_bnb_4bit.py", line 219, in create_quantized_param
    new_value = bnb.nn.Params4bit(new_value, requires_grad=False, **kwargs).to(target_device)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 191, in to
    return self.cuda(device)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/cluster/home/username/llama/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 168, in cuda
    w = self.data.contiguous().half().cuda(device)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 112.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 23.64 GiB of which 42.50 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 23.60 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 1002.01 MiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.99 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management

Now if I remove the line import flan.v2.mixtures, it works as intended and I get the following output
|===========================================================================|
|                  PyTorch CUDA memory summary, device ID 0                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            CUDA OOMs: 0            |        cudaMalloc retries: 0         |
|===========================================================================|
|        Metric         | Cur Usage  | Peak Usage | Tot Alloc  | Tot Freed  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocated memory      |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active memory         |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Requested memory      |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved memory   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable memory |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from large pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|       from small pool |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |      0 B   |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocations           |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active allocs         |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved segments |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable allocs |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from large pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|       from small pool |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize allocations  |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize GPU segments |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|===========================================================================|

`low_cpu_mem_usage` was None, now set to True since model is quantized.

Loading checkpoint shards:   0%|          | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Loading checkpoint shards:  25%|██▌       | 1/4 [00:07<00:21,  7.18s/it]
Loading checkpoint shards:  50%|█████     | 2/4 [00:12<00:12,  6.25s/it]
Loading checkpoint shards:  75%|███████▌  | 3/4 [00:18<00:05,  5.86s/it]
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:19<00:00,  4.06s/it]
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:19<00:00,  4.87s/it]
|===========================================================================|
|                  PyTorch CUDA memory summary, device ID 0                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            CUDA OOMs: 0            |        cudaMalloc retries: 0         |
|===========================================================================|
|        Metric         | Cur Usage  | Peak Usage | Tot Alloc  | Tot Freed  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocated memory      |   5908 MiB |   5908 MiB |  19221 MiB |  13313 MiB |
|       from large pool |   5827 MiB |   5827 MiB |  19141 MiB |  13313 MiB |
|       from small pool |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |      0 MiB |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active memory         |   5908 MiB |   5908 MiB |  19221 MiB |  13313 MiB |
|       from large pool |   5827 MiB |   5827 MiB |  19141 MiB |  13313 MiB |
|       from small pool |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |      0 MiB |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Requested memory      |   5876 MiB |   5876 MiB |  19188 MiB |  13312 MiB |
|       from large pool |   5796 MiB |   5796 MiB |  19108 MiB |  13312 MiB |
|       from small pool |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |     80 MiB |      0 MiB |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved memory   |   5934 MiB |   5986 MiB |  10414 MiB |   4480 MiB |
|       from large pool |   5852 MiB |   5904 MiB |  10332 MiB |   4480 MiB |
|       from small pool |     82 MiB |     82 MiB |     82 MiB |      0 MiB |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable memory |  26488 KiB | 131745 KiB |   1947 MiB |   1921 MiB |
|       from large pool |  25088 KiB | 130048 KiB |   1899 MiB |   1875 MiB |
|       from small pool |   1400 KiB |   2040 KiB |     47 MiB |     46 MiB |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Allocations           |     835    |     835    |    1059    |     224    |
|       from large pool |     386    |     386    |     610    |     224    |
|       from small pool |     449    |     449    |     449    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Active allocs         |     835    |     835    |    1059    |     224    |
|       from large pool |     386    |     386    |     610    |     224    |
|       from small pool |     449    |     449    |     449    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| GPU reserved segments |     189    |     189    |     249    |      60    |
|       from large pool |     148    |     148    |     208    |      60    |
|       from small pool |      41    |      41    |      41    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Non-releasable allocs |      15    |      17    |     151    |     136    |
|       from large pool |      12    |      14    |     110    |      98    |
|       from small pool |       3    |       4    |      41    |      38    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize allocations  |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Oversize GPU segments |       0    |       0    |       0    |       0    |
|===========================================================================|

I am confused, because it seems that the memory should be empty in both cases, but in one the model has enough space on the GPU and in the other case it doesn't? What is the source for this error?
